# How to see the output of the SQL function in ORACLE using Toad by passing manual parameter values

Tags: oracle, toad, sql-function

I'm new to the Oracle database and TOAD. I need to run this function `GET_WRKFLW_LICENSE_LIMIT` in TOAD and see its output.

parameter values are:

```
GET_WRKFLW_LICENSE_LIMIT('MSG_FORMAT', 1, NULL, NULL)
```

Here below, I have attached my code.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION MYSCHEMA.GET_WRKFLW_LICENSE_LIMIT (
   WRK_TYPE IN VARCHAR2, VCLIENT_ID IN NUMBER, VCP_ID IN NUMBER, VREQ_TYPE  IN VARCHAR2)
   RETURN BOOLEAN
 IS
   RESULT                   BOOLEAN;
   vWRK_FLW_LIST_COUNT      NUMBER (5);
   vWRK_FLW_LICENCE_LIMIT   NUMBER (5);
 BEGIN
      IF (WRK_TYPE = 'MSG_FORMAT') THEN
      SELECT COUNT (*)
        INTO vWRK_FLW_LIST_COUNT
        FROM (SELECT MSG_TMPL_ID
                FROM MYSCHEMA.VW_MSG_TMPL_FORMAT
               WHERE     NVL (CLIENT_ID, 1) = NVL (VCLIENT_ID, 1)
                     AND NVL (CP_ID, 1) = NVL (VCP_ID, 1));
      BEGIN
         SELECT TO_NUMBER (PARAM_VALUE)
           INTO vWRK_FLW_LICENCE_LIMIT
           FROM CONFIG.ENV_PARAMS
           WHERE PARAM_NAME = 'TT_MSG_TMPL_THRESHOLD';
         IF     vWRK_FLW_LICENCE_LIMIT IS NOT NULL
            AND (vWRK_FLW_LIST_COUNT <= vWRK_FLW_LICENCE_LIMIT) THEN
            RESULT := TRUE;
         ELSIF vWRK_FLW_LICENCE_LIMIT IS NULL THEN
            RESULT := TRUE;
         ELSE
            RESULT := FALSE;
         END IF;
      EXCEPTION
         WHEN OTHERS  THEN
            RESULT := FALSE;
            RETURN RESULT;
    END;
    EXCEPTION
        WHEN OTHERS THEN
           RESULT := FALSE;
            RETURN RESULT;
    END;
    /
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your function has two major problems.

The first is it only executes RETURN RESULT in exception blocks. So although it compile it will hurl on runtime with `PLS-06503: Function returned without value`. So you need to add a RETURN RESULT before the last exception block:

```
         ....
     END;
     RETURN RESULT;
 EXCEPTION
    WHEN OTHERS ....
```

The other problem is that it returns a Boolean. That means you cannot run it in SQL: it will hurl `ORA-00902: Invalid datatype`.

So you can test this in TOAD with an anonymous PL/SQL block:

```
begin 
     if GET_WRKFLW_LICENSE_LIMIT (
           WRK_TYPE    => 'MSG_FORMAT',
           VCLIENT_ID => 1,
           VCP_ID    => null,
           VREQ_TYPE  => null)
    then
        dbms_output.put_line('True!');
    else
        dbms_output.put_line('False!');
    end if;
end;
```

Remember to enable DBMS_OUTPUT in TOAD if it's not set in your preferences.

Alternatively you might decide to rewrite your query so it uses a datatype supported in SQL e.g. varchar2.

Comment: Thank you so much for your support  [APC](http://stackoverflow.com/users/146325/apc). and sorry for the delay.